# Problem with IRC socket connection

Tags: c++, sockets, connection, irc

Error occurs during JOIN and USER, it tells me I need to "Register first". The three: PASS, NICK work correctly (probably). Any idea how is this possible? I've followed the relevant RFC, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.1

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
unsigned long resolveHost(const string &host){
    LPHOSTENT entryHost = gethostbyname(host.c_str());

    if(!entryHost){
        unsigned int addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
        entryHost = gethostbyaddr((char*)&addr, 4, AF_INET);
        if(!entryHost)  return 0;
    }
    return *((int*)*entryHost->h_addr_list);
}

int main(){
    WSADATA         wsaData;
    SOCKADDR_IN     saddr;
    SOCKET          sock;
    char            buffer[1024*8] = {"0"};
    string          adres_hosta = "irc.example.com";
    string          sbuffer;
    string          nick = "johnsmith";
    string          kanal = "#channel";
    string          password = "p@55w0rd";
    string          auth = "/AuthServ auth johnsmith p@55w0rd";
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    saddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = resolveHost(adres_hosta);
    saddr.sin_port =  htons(6667);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "Nie udalo sie nawiazac polaczenia z " << adres_hosta << ".";
        return 0;
    }
    recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
    cout << buffer << endl << endl << flush;
    /*
           1. Pass message
           2. Nick message
           3. User message
    */
    sbuffer ="PASS " + password + "\r\n";
    send(sock, sbuffer.c_str(), strlen(sbuffer.c_str()), 0);
    recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
    cout << sbuffer.c_str() << endl << buffer << endl << endl;

    sbuffer = "NICK " + nick + "\r\n";
    send(sock, sbuffer.c_str(), strlen(sbuffer.c_str()), 0);
    recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
    cout << sbuffer.c_str() << endl << buffer << endl << endl;

    sbuffer = "USER " + nick + " " + adres_hosta + " " + nick + " :" + nick + "\r\n";
    send(sock, sbuffer.c_str(), strlen(sbuffer.c_str()), 0);
    recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
    cout << sbuffer.c_str() << endl << buffer << endl << endl;

    sbuffer = "JOIN " + kanal + "\r\n";
    send(sock, sbuffer.c_str(), strlen(sbuffer.c_str()), 0);
    recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
    cout << sbuffer.c_str() << endl << buffer << endl << endl;

    while(true){
        recv(sock, buffer, 1024*8, 0);
        cout << buffer << endl << endl;
        if(buffer[0] == 'PING'){
            sbuffer = "PONG :" + adres_hosta + "\r\n";
            send(sock, sbuffer.c_str(), strlen(sbuffer.c_str()), 0);
            cout << sbuffer.c_str() << endl << buffer << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

logs with connection :

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname


PASS p@55w0rd

NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking Ident
NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname


NICK johnsmith

PING :229860947
Checking Ident
NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname


USER johnsmith johnSmith test :johnSmith

NOTICE AUTH :*** No ident response
ICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname


JOIN #channel

:server.example.com 451 johnSmith johnSmith :Register first.
```

Comment: I'll add one comment: many, many IRC servers have moved quite a ways beyond the 1993 RFC at this point, adding a variety of features and modes that are occasionally documented--but not always. There may not be a single major IRC network that is strictly RFC-compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that, to join that specific channel, your nickname must be registered with NickServ or equivalent IRC services. You'll probably have to register the nickname you're using with NickServ (I suggest using a regular IRC client to do this to make it easier) and then, from your code, PRIVMSG NickServ with some sort of auth command to "log in" before it will allow you to join that channel. There's probably a channel mode that controls whether non-authorized users are allowed to join.

If you aren't already, I would suggest using an empty, unregistered channel for doing your testing. It helps to be able to control the test environment, and you don't have curious people trying to break your software while you're in the middle of developing it.